# React Native: Package to select multiple images from the device and sort by selection order?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native and am developing functionality for the user to select multiple photos and sort the photos by the user's selection order--just like what Instagram does, for example.

Found out that currently popular image selection packages for react native don't serve this purpose:

[React native image picker](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker) : Can select one image at a time

[React native image crop picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker): Can select multiple images, but sorts by image creation time, not selection order.

Is there a package to do this? If not, what might be workaround? Will I have to rely on native codes to achieve this? (Which I want to avoid as much as possible)

Thanks a lot in advance!